# Update Statement using Join and Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, group-by, sql-update

I have written the below Update Statement, but it shows the error such as "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'."

```
UPDATE 
       J
SET 
       J.StatusID = CASE WHEN SUM(DUV.VendorDUQuantity) = SUM(RD.InvoiceQuantity) THEN 1 ELSE J.StatusID END
FROM
        PLN_DU_Vendor DUV
    INNER JOIN ENG_Release R ON R.ReleaseID = DUV.ReleaseID
    INNER JOIN ENG_DU_Header H ON H.ReleaseID = R.ReleaseID AND DUV.DUID = H.DUID
    INNER JOIN MKT_JobOrder J ON J.JobOrderID = R.JobOrderID
    INNER JOIN MKT_CustomerOrder CO ON CO.OrderID = J.OrderID
    LEFT JOIN PMT_RFDHeader RH ON RH.JobOrderID = J.JobOrderID
    LEFT JOIN PMT_RFDDetail RD ON RD.RFDID = RH.RFDID AND RD.DUID = DUV.DUID                 
WHERE 
        CO.OrderID = 100
GROUP BY 
        J.JobOrderID
```

Instead of Update, Select is working perfectly for the above Query. What would be the problem and How to write the Query based on Join and Group By clause.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can try putting the group by inside of a subquery, then join by the "JobOrderID", like this:

```
UPDATE J
SET J.StatusID = A.statusId
FROM MKT_JobOrder J
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT J.JobOrderID
        , CASE 
            WHEN SUM(DUV.VendorDUQuantity) = SUM(RD.InvoiceQuantity)
                THEN 1
            ELSE J.StatusID
            END AS statusId 
    FROM PLN_DU_Vendor DUV
    INNER JOIN ENG_Release R ON R.ReleaseID = DUV.ReleaseID
    INNER JOIN ENG_DU_Header H ON H.ReleaseID = R.ReleaseID
                               AND DUV.DUID = H.DUID
    INNER JOIN MKT_JobOrder J ON J.JobOrderID = R.JobOrderID
    INNER JOIN MKT_CustomerOrder CO ON CO.OrderID = J.OrderID
    LEFT JOIN PMT_RFDHeader RH ON RH.JobOrderID = J.JobOrderID
    LEFT JOIN PMT_RFDDetail RD ON RD.RFDID = RH.RFDID
                               AND RD.DUID = DUV.DUID
    WHERE CO.OrderID = 100
    GROUP BY J.JobOrderID
           , J.StatusID
    ) A ON J.JobOrderID = A.JobOrderID
```

Answer (score 4):

User sub query instead to perform this operation

```
UPDATE 
   J
 SET StatusID = x.Status
   FROM 
   (select CASE WHEN SUM(DUV.VendorDUQuantity) = SUM(RD.InvoiceQuantity) THEN 1 
    ELSE   J.StatusID END as Status 
     JobOrderID
     FROM
    PLN_DU_Vendor DUV
    INNER JOIN ENG_Release R ON R.ReleaseID = DUV.ReleaseID
    INNER JOIN ENG_DU_Header H ON H.ReleaseID = R.ReleaseID AND DUV.DUID = H.DUID
INNER JOIN MKT_JobOrder J ON J.JobOrderID = R.JobOrderID
INNER JOIN MKT_CustomerOrder CO ON CO.OrderID = J.OrderID
LEFT JOIN PMT_RFDHeader RH ON RH.JobOrderID = J.JobOrderID
LEFT JOIN PMT_RFDDetail RD ON RD.RFDID = RH.RFDID AND RD.DUID = DUV.DUID                 
WHERE 
    CO.OrderID = 100
 GROUP BY 
    J.JobOrderID) X
 INNER JOIN MKT_JobOrder J On x.JobOrderID = J.JobOrderID
```

Comment: Your query won't work. There're two JobOrderId columns, you should specify which one it should use.