# SQL Server Count

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation where I need to count the number of records (Lines) for each job number in the jobtable. I have the following select script which does this.

```
Select job, COUNT (*) AS 'Lines'
FROM jobtable
GROUP BY job


Job       Lines
--------- --------
1         26

2         12

3         46
...
```

Now I would like to update a second table "materials" using the result of the count in a column called 'time'. So in the table called materials where the job = 1 update time = 26, where job is = 2 update the time = 12 etc ......

Comment: This may help, pretty similar - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12225715/update-statement-using-join-and-group-by.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below, joining your `materials` table with your current query result

```
UPDATE
    m
SET
    [time] = lines
FROM
    materials m
    JOIN
(
Select job, COUNT (*) AS 'Lines'
FROM jobtable
GROUP BY job
) tab on m.job = tab.job
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer provided by Rahul, if you're on SQL Server 2005 or later, you can use a [CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which I personally find more readily understandable than constructions using subqueries:

```
with CountsCTE as
(
    select [job], count(*) as [lines]
    from [jobtable]
    group by [job]
)
update [materials]
set [time] = C.[lines]
from [materials] M
    inner join [CountsCTE] C on M.[job] = C.[job];
```

If you're on SQL Server 2008 or later, you can replace the `UPDATE` with a [`MERGE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx):

```
with CountsCTE as
(
    select [job], count(*) as [lines]
    from [jobtable]
    group by [job]
)
merge into [materials] M
    using [CountsCTE] C on M.[job] = C.[job]
    when matched then update set M.[time] = C.[lines];
```